# Select a two table join in one result row

Tags: sql

I have two tables

`Table A` with three columns: `AID, first name, surname`

`Tabel B` with four columns: `BID, AID, Address, TypeOFAddress`

Each person in table A has four rows each in table B.

```
Table_A
_AID_|_FIRST_|_LAST_
  1  | Leo   | White
  2  | Joe   | Black


Table_B
_BID_|_AID_|_ADDRESS_|_TYPE_
  10 |  1  |Street 1 |STREET
  11 |  1  |23490878 |ZIPCODE
  12 |  1  |Town 1   |CITY
  13 |  1  |Street 2 |STREET
  14 |  1  |83083099 |ZIPCODE
  15 |  1  |Town 2   |CITY
```

I want to select these rows in one row so the result output is

```
Result output
1  |Leo   |White |Street 1 |23490878 |Town
2  |Joe   |Black |Street 2 |83083099 |Town 2
```

How do I do this in a nice way?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Will the types be fixed?

Comment: Right now a AS400 and yes the types will be fixed.
I edited the question a bit

Comment: If you are using microsoft sql server you should look up pivot and unpivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `JOIN` the tables. Then use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.AID, t1.FIRST, t1.LAST,
       max(case when t2.TypeOFAddress = 'STREET' then t2.Address end) STREET,
       max(case when t2.TypeOFAddress = 'ZIPCODE' then t2.Address end) ZIPCODE,
       max(case when t2.TypeOFAddress = 'CITY' then t2.Address end) CITY
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.AID = t2.AID_
group by t1.AID, t1.FIRST, t1.LAST
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT` if you are using Microsoft SQL Server

```
SELECT * FROM
    ( SELECT A.*, B.ADDRESS, B.TYPE 
      FROM Table_A A 
          INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.AID = B.AID 
     ) SRC
    PIVOT (MAX([ADDRESS]) FOR TYPE IN ([STREET],[ZIPCODE],[CITY])) PVT
```